# Can you give a Modal Window (using Twitter-Bootstrap) a z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, qtip2

I have a form using Qtip2 and if the user submits the form with invalid values, the qTips fire correctly (so far so good).  However, say the user wants clicks on a button that triggers the modal window to appear, the modal window appears above the form but below the qtips.  So, I'm thinking, just give the Modal window a higher z-index value.

[Modal Example with qTip](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8290/7844787446_57cd3f89a6.jpg)

Has anyone else run across this behavior and what did you do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lastest version of bootstrap shows the modal has a z-index of 1050. I believe the default z-index of qTip2 is 15001, and goes higher from there. You would have to up the z-index of the modal.

Edited: Removed incorrect information.

Comment: I would try to adjust the default qTip z-index down if possible

Comment: @Christoph Good to know! Thanks!.  Kenny Bania - The plugin adds one to the z-index every time you add a qTip so I'm not sure that would be so easy